# Word position search

Tags: python

How can I search for specific words in a string from a dataframe column and print the position location for every instance identified of the target words? When I say position location, I mean the number of words proceeding it + 1, *NOT* the starting character position.

[Sample Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT7nb.png)

How would I call that “Text” column in the dataframe while also appending/retaining the corresponding “Record ID” in the output as a new dataframe?

Also, my dataframes are sourced from a very large database, so the search function needs to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Search word position in string is

```py
[i+1 for i, w in enumerate("test a d test foo bar test".split()) if w == 'test']
# [1, 4, 7]
```

Use this in dataframe well

Comment: This is inefficient for getting the position of every word